# Formulation of a suspension of Magnesium Hydroxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, polymers

For a school project of mine, I have to formulate a suspension of Magnesium Hydroxide which contains at least 50% of solid matter.

This suspension is prepared from Magnesium Oxide 98% with a granulometry of around 75 micrometers. Unfortunately, I don't have a way to crush it more than it is until it is the ultimate solution.

The hydratation process will be made prior to the addition of additives to maintain the whole thing in suspension.

As my particles are relatively large and heavy, I know I have to fight against gravity. For that, I need additives that have dispersive properties and allow the mix to have a decent viscosity while avoiding sedimentation.

But, as I'm more specialized in enviromental chemistry, I'm not very good at proposing which surfactant/dispersant would be the most suitable for this project even after in-depth studies of papers talking about this.

From what I know, I think a polymer could seal the deal ? Maybe Sodium Polyacrylate as I saw it works fine with Calcium. Some Polyelectrolyte ? Or even multiple additives ? And in what quantities ?

I don't even know if the project is viable without crushing the particles of MgO so if you have any idea, I thank you in advance for your answer.

S.Berthels